# Where did the com.sun.mirror.* package go on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, apt, annotation-processing

I'm currently trying to write an apt annotation processor. I can however not find the required tools.jar on my system. I'm on OSX, having installed the default JDK. Where can i find the apt-related classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tools.jar in the Apple-bundled JVMs, those classes are simply in classes.jar, which contains the other base Java library files (on my machine, here: `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar`).

Comment: That being said, you may want to rely on the new Java 6 annotation-processor system instead of the old-style Java 5 one.

Comment: How does one test annotation processors? Do I programmatically start a compiler and feed it with processors and fake source files?

Comment: The best way I've found so far is to develop them form Eclipse and test them as regular Eclipse plug-ins, and finally, when they're ready, use them with javac. Look for documentation on how to develop and test Eclipse plug-ins and read about the JDT APT project (Eclipse has very good annotation processing support).

Answer (score 2):

`com.sun.*` classes must not be relied on. They are internal implementation and the risk is they will go away in the next version or on a different platform.

Comment: Those specific com.sun classes are reimplemented in the Eclipse JDT APT plugins, so if you're willing to use Eclipse, you always have this fallback option.